# Pygame mask collision. Using a transparent image as background not working

Tags: python, pygame, collision, mask

I'm having trouble trying to understand why i cant get the mask collision to work. I'm trying to use a background image(Racetrack class) that has transparent areas the car object can 'drive' in. However i cant seem to get it to work. Collide function will only return none once the car has moved outside off the background image area. I've also tried placing the sprites into groups, but i couldn't get that to work either.

```
import pygame

from pygame.math import Vector2

from math import radians, tan, degrees, copysign

pygame.init()

width = 1920
height = 900
hWidth = width/2
hHeight = height/2

SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF
global screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), SURFACE)

time = pygame.time.Clock()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

white = (255,255,255)
grey = (105,105,105)

class Race_car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        x = 32.6
        y = 26.3
        self.pos = Vector2(x, y)
        self.velocity = Vector2(0.0, 0.0)
        self.angle = 0.0
        self.length = 4
        self.maxAcceleration = 10
        self.maxSteering = 50
        self.maxVelocity = 17
        self.brakeDeceleration = 20
        self.freeDeceleration = 6
        self.acceleration = 0.0
        self.steering = 0.0
        self.dt = clock.get_time() / 1000
        self.image = pygame.image.load('F1 Car1.png').convert_alpha()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.rotated.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.dt = clock.get_time() / 1000

        self.velocity += (self.acceleration * self.dt, 0)
        self.velocity.x = max(-self.maxVelocity, min(self.velocity.x, self.maxVelocity))

        if self.steering:
            turningRadius = self.length / tan(radians(self.steering))
            angular_velocity = self.velocity.x / turningRadius
        else:
            angular_velocity = 0

        self.pos += self.velocity.rotate(-self.angle) * self.dt
        self.angle += degrees(angular_velocity) * self.dt

        center_x = round(self.pos.x)
        center_y = round(self.pos.y)
        self.rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.rotated.get_rect(center=(center_x, center_y))

        screen.blit(self.rotated, self.pos * 32 - (self.rect.width / 2, self.rect.height / 2))

    def controls(self):

        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            if self.velocity.x < 0:
                self.acceleration = +self.brakeDeceleration
            self.acceleration += 400 * self.dt
        elif pressed[pygame.KEYDOWN]:
            if self.velocity.x < 0:
                self.acceleration = -self.brakeDeceleration
            else:
                self.acceleration -= 5 * self.dt
        elif pressed[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            if abs(self.velocity.x) > self.dt * self.brakeDeceleration:
                self.acceleration = -copysign(self.brakeDeceleration, self.velocity.x)
            else:
                self.acceleration = -self.velocity.x / self.dt
        else:
            if abs(self.velocity.x) > self.dt * self.freeDeceleration:
                self.acceleration = -copysign(self.freeDeceleration, self.velocity.x)
            else:
                if self.dt != 0:
                    self.acceleration = -self.velocity.x / self.dt
        self.acceleration = max(-self.maxAcceleration, min(self.acceleration, self.maxAcceleration))

        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.steering -= 400 * self.dt
        elif pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.steering += 400 * self.dt
        else:
            self.steering = 0
        self.steering = max(-self.maxSteering, min(self.steering, self.maxSteering))


class Finish_Line(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, finish_image):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(finish_image).convert_alpha()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(1190, 803))

    def update(self):
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

class Racetrack(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.image = pygame.image.load('pixil mask.png')
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image.convert_alpha())
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        center_x = round(self.x)
        center_y = round(self.y)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(center_x, center_y))
        screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)


finish = Finish_Line('FinishSt.jpg')
car = Race_car()
track = Racetrack(0,0,1920,1080)

track_image = pygame.image.load('pixil mask.png').convert_alpha()
track_mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(track_image)
track_rect = track_image.get_rect()

markings = pygame.image.load('markings (1).png')


def check_for_collisions():
    offset = (int(car.rect.x), int(car.rect.y))
    collide = track.mask.overlap(car.mask, offset)
    print(offset, collide)
    return collide

class Game:    # initialize game class
    def __init__(self):

        pygame.display.set_caption("2D Racer")

        self.running = True

    def run(self):

        while self.running:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False

            check_for_collisions()

            screen.fill(grey)
            track.update()
            finish.update()
            screen.blit(markings, (974, 812))
            car.update()
            car.controls()
            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(60)

        pygame.quit()


g = Game()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    g.run()
```

Comment: *"that has transparent areas the car object can 'drive' in"* - Mask collision detects the collision between non-transparent areas.

Comment: yeah yeah i know that, the car will be moving around in the transparent area, and will collide with the non transparent area. Do you have any suggestions, that could fix my code

Comment: I've provided a complete answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see 3 problems:

---

The position of the car is `self.pos * 32 - (self.rect.width / 2, self.rect.height / 2)`. This is the position where the car is "`blit`":

> ```py
> screen.blit(self.rotated, self.pos * 32 - (self.rect.width / 2, self.rect.height / 2))
> ```

The position stored in the `rect` attribute needs to be updated with the position of the car image on the screen:

```py
class Race_car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        # [...]

        screen_pos = self.pos * 32 - (self.rect.width / 2, self.rect.height / 2)
        left = round(screen_pos.x)
        top = round(screen_pos.y)
        self.rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.rotated.get_rect(topleft = (left, top))

        screen.blit(self.rotated, self.pos * 32 - (self.rect.width / 2, self.rect.height / 2))
```

---

For the collision detection you have calculate the offset between the car and the track:

```py
def check_for_collisions():
   
    offset = car.rect.x - track.rect.x, car.rect.y - track.rect.y
   
    collide = track.mask.overlap(car.mask, offset)
    print(offset, collide)
    return collide
```

Since you are using [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), you can simplify the code with [`pygame.sprite.collide_mask()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask):

```py
def check_for_collisions():
    collide = pygame.sprite.collide_mask(car, track)
    print(collide)
    return collide
```

---

In your question you mentioned:

> I'm trying to use a background image(Racetrack class) that has transparent areas the car object can 'drive' in.

Mask collision detects the collision between non-transparent areas. Therefore it may be necessary to invert the background mask. Flips all of the bits in the mask with [`invert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.Mask.invert):

```py
class Racetrack(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.image = pygame.image.load('pixil mask.png')
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image.convert_alpha())
        
        self.mask.invert()
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Comment: i actually love you! Wow, it worked a charm!